# How can I express that a type must be one of union in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to do something like this:

```
type Whoozit = string | number

type WhoozitMap = {[key: string]: (x: Whoozit) => boolean}

const whoozit: WhoozitMap = {
    cheese: (x: string) => x === 'cheese',
    digit:  (x: number) => x < 10
}
```

But this doesn't work; the type of the functions in the map must be `Whoozit`, not either `string` or `number`. So I can fix this two ways:

```
const whoozit: WhoozitMap = {
    cheese: (x: Whoozit) => { if (isString(x)) { return x === 'cheese' } else { return false } },
    digit: (x: number)  => { if (isNumber(x)) { return x < 10 } else { return false } },
}

// Ok, but I trust my code at runtime to pick the right key 
// in the map, so I don't want all this extra complexity
```

or

```
type WhoozitMap = {[key: string]: (x: any) => boolean}

// nice and clean, but now I've lost *all* type safety in my map
```

Is there a way to express what I want in Typescript? Specifically, this should compile:

```
const whoozit: WhoozitMap = {
    cheese: (x: string) => x === 'cheese',
    digit:  (x: number) => x < 10
}
```

... but this (for example) should not?

```
const whoozit: WhoozitMap = {
    cheese: (x: string) => x === 'cheese',
    list:   (x: number[]) => x.includes(22) // ❌ number[] does not extend Whoozit
}
```

See [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gFgewQLwJbCgXigZ2AJ1QDsBzKAHyiIFcBbAIwnwChnRJZEV0BZAQzBYoAbwDaAawggAXLgLESAXVkAKAB6z4SNMACUWAHxR6SADYQ+RAL6sAxgiJ4oAdy47Nb3gKHDmUf3KEpKoagQr6mEZqWJjYAOS2cBAQOBBxADR+ATQMTCGyOYz4EVFQADxQAEyVzFZAA).

Comment: ① the `key` in your mapped type (with `in` after it) is a type parameter, not an identifier. It should be `Key` or `K` to be conventional. Mapped types and index signatures are different syntaxes and use different conventions ② You have to write a mapping yourself, there's nothing that relates the *strings* `"string"`/`"number"` to the *types* `string`/`number`.  You could change `Whoosit` to be that mapping and then `WhoositMap` could map over it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLO9KN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think I oversimplified a bit in my original question. I don't actually know at compile time what the enumerated keys in `WhoozitMap` are, so they actually are type `string`. I've edited the question to avoid confusion -- does that help?

Comment: If you don't know at compile time what the keys are, how do you "trust my code at runtime to pick the right key"?  You can use `((x: string) => boolean) | ((x: number) => boolean)` instead of `(x: Whoozit) => boolean` but [good luck calling one of those](https://tsplay.dev/w2gKbN).  I guess I don't understand the use case; it sounds like you want to both give up and preserve type safety. How would you like to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

you can define the WhoozitMap type to expect functions that take a Whoozit type as an argument, and then correctly assign functions that meet this requirement

```
type Whoozit = string | number;

type WhoozitMap = {
    [Key in 'string' | 'number']: (x: Whoozit) => boolean;
};

const whoozit: WhoozitMap = {
    string: (x: Whoozit) => typeof x === 'string' && x === 'cheese',
    number: (x: Whoozit) => typeof x === 'number' && x < 22
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is of course to spread the type outside of the function:

```
type WhoozitFunction = ((x: number) => boolean) | ((x: string) => boolean)
type WhoozitMap = {[key: string]: WhoozitFunction}
```

But I assume you want to reuse `Whoozit`

For that you can use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type ToPredicate<Type> = Type extends any ? (x: Type) => boolean : never;
type WhoozitMap = {[key: string]: ToPredicate<Whoozit>}
```

which resolves to the same thing as above.